# How to add multi line text in ui grid column?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose there  are $scope.gridoptions.columns =[ 5cols]. I need to make one of the ui grid column to wrap to multi line text area. On click of  edit cell, it should come in multi line format

Comment: possibly related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394562/angularjs-ui-grid-show-multi-lines-in-a-cell

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try a custom-template? what was the issue? Provide your code.